# When can the relative pronouns "who", "which", "that" etc. be safely omitted?

Tags: relative-pronouns, omissibility, whiz-deletion

For example, instead of

> The guy ***who*** is beside me is a jerk

I can say

> The guy **beside** me is a jerk.

It is okay if I don't use the relative pronoun here, either way is correct. But instead of "The guy ***who*** sits beside me is a jerk" I cannot say "The guy sits beside me is a jerk." And I cannot say "The people sit beside me are jerks." or "The people sit beside me keep changing." etc.

- What is the rule about this? In what situations do I have a chance to not to use the relative pronoun?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To avoid ambiguity, what is your opinion about how to use reduced relative clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387893/to-avoid-ambiguity-what-is-your-opinion-about-how-to-use-reduced-relative-claus)

Answer (score 1):

1. The guy who is beside me is a jerk.
2. The guy beside me is a jerk.

The rule we use here is a *reduced relative clause (hereafter, RRC)*.* RRC allows you to delete the relative pronoun (and sometimes the form of *BE*<sup>†</sup>) and transform the remaining elements into a different kind of modifier. #1, for example, is a noun phrase modified by a relative clause; but the reduced form #2 is a  noun phrase modified by a prepositional phrase—'beside me'.

3. The guy who sits behind me is a jerk

RRC can also be applied to #3. The relative clause can be transformed into a post-modifying gerund-participle clause.

"The guy **sitting behind me** is a jerk."

---

*<sub>Sometimes analyzed as a *whiz-deletion* because the deleted words are usually the *wh-word + is* (whiz).</sub>

<sup>†</sup><sub>Forms of *BE* are *be, is, are, was, were, and am*.</sub>

Comment: Thank you but that "sitting behind me" instance sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @DereMemo No, it's perfectly fine. You can find lots of instances on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abooks.google.com+%22guy+sitting%22&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=ssl)