# "If not for his wide, thin lips, perpetually drawn in a single disapproving line, she would have liked him too."

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis, sentence

I am not sure about the grammatical correctness of the above sentence. I am writing a fictional short story and this sentence is part of the narrative.

My friend says it should be "If not for his wide, thin lips, *which were* perpetually drawn in a single disapproving line, she would have been attracted to him too."

But even that sounds a bit odd to me. Can anyone confirm which one is correct, and if neither, then how can it be framed using the same structure.

Comment: Your example, according to a widely held analysis, uses 'whiz-deletion' (**wh**ich were; compare **wh**ich **is**) and to my ears sounds the better version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can the relative pronouns "who", "which", "that" etc. be safely omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406389/when-can-the-relative-pronouns-who-which-that-etc-be-safely-omitted) (and many others; search for 'reduced relative clause'; 'whiz deletion').

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!