# Participle phrases that don't follow the main clause

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> The book was boring, and as stupid as the last one, *punctuated by silly mistakes.*

Is it unambiguous? Is it grammatical?

I'm asking if it's grammatical because I want to know whether you can offset a participle phrase at the end of a sentence like that, as it does not immediately follow the main clause. Is it ambiguous as to whether both books have silly mistakes?

I can't post the actual sentence I'm thinking about, sorry.

Comment: PP at the end of the clause?

Comment: Structurally / syntactically, it's unquestionably "ambiguous". You've only got to compare the two different parsings if we replace *...punctuated by silly mistakes* (which is ***semantically*** ambiguous) with 1) *...written before he signed a major publishing deal* and 2) *...written purely to cash in on that earlier success*. It should be obvious that the final clause in 1) refers to the *previous* book, but in 2) it refers to the *current* book. In short, the construction can only be interpreted using common sense, which in *some* cases might not be sufficient to disambiguate.

Comment: right thanks @FumbleFingers that makes sense.

Comment: So what PP are you referring to?

Comment: I thought "punctuated..." would be a prepositional phrase. is it not @BillJ ?

Comment: No: it's a past-participial clause headed by the verb "punctuated".

Comment: yeah I meant participle, damn sorry @BillJ

Comment: In a *language* context, PP usually stands for Past Participle, not Prepositional Phrase (though presumably sometimes they're actually the same thing). But the example context would still be much the same with, something like ***... not worth reading*** or ***...with no merit***. They're just relative clauses with an ambiguous (prior) referent.

Comment: I *think* the issue being raised here might be  the same as [To avoid ambiguity, what is your opinion about how to use reduced relative clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387893/to-avoid-ambiguity-what-is-your-opinion-about-how-to-use-reduced-relative-claus) Also probably [Ambiguous relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158116/ambiguous-relative-clause), but the connection's not so obvious there.

Comment: No it doesn't. PP is the standard abbreviation for preposition phrase, and past participles and preposition phrases can never be the same thing. Further, "punctuated by silly mistakes" is not some kind of relative clause, but a past-participial clause, functioning as a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: this is all really confusing @BillJ personally feel we need something between ELL and this stack

Comment: did we establish, independent of *why*, if the example sentence is ungrammatical @FumbleFingers

Comment: As implied by my first comment, *syntactically*, the construction is perfectly valid regardless of whether the speaker/writer intends that final clause (a "past-participial clause" - thanks, @BillJ :) to apply to the *main* clause (*The book was boring*, in your example), or to the immediately-preceding clause (as is *usually* the case). In practice, with your example it's most likely that *both* books were punctuated by silly mistakes (that's probably why they're both unambiguously being labelled "stupid"). But syntactically, only one (not "explicitly" identified) actually contains mistakes.

Comment: ok cool, thanks @FumbleFingers I think I get what you mean by "actually" but it's confusingly stated, as I think of "actual" as a kind of possible world (lol) so yeah. and likewise, easier to state than imply.

Comment: Agreed, my use of the word "actually" there is a bit strained. That's because I wasn't "actually" (?!) referring to the "actual, real-world" situation. I was talking about the information explicitly conveyed by the ***text / syntax*** itself (which the reader may extend through his own knowledge of "how things work in the real world", for certain things that aren't *explicitly* stated).